# Parse.com querying all users in a tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

How would I go about displaying a list of all users in the parse.com database in a tableview and then when they click on each table, display that particular user's information.

All I know is that in order to query the users I must use:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

Thank you in advance and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You really should try writing a bit more code on your own before coming here for answers... The Parse docs are robust, easy to read, and full of relevant examples. I'd suggest starting there.

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking a specific question about Parse queries, but it seems like you don't understand queries in general, so just start with a general query against Parse:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Something went wrong
    } else {
        // objects is an array of PFObject containing your results
    }
}];
```

As you figured out, you can also do a user query by making that first line:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

The rest is the same.

Lyndsey Scott is right, this is basic stuff in the docs.  I'm posting this here because of the one "gotcha" which is the class name (_User instead of User) if you use the first method.

What you generally will do is call [myTableView reloadData] inside the success block since you now have an array of users.  In your `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` perform a seque with a new viewcontroller, and in your `prepareForSegue` method, pass the user object to your pushed view controller so it knows what user to show.

Comment: excellent. you saved my day. Somehow the user table cannot be queried by it's name, i.e "User". _User works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to use table view. So I'll implement it this way:

1.create a property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *users;
```

2.In viewDidAppear execute the query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query setLimit:1000];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.users = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

3.You need to implement table view code, the most important is cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"userCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    PFUser *user = self.users[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = user.username;
    return cell;
}
```

Beside that you also need all of the required table view's data source code to tell it the number of cell. If you'll need some help with that just tell.